How to add a variable from a step to strategy matrix
I have a GitHub Actions workflow  having APP_APPROVALS and DB_APPROVALS as two hard-coded strategy matrix that is used as environments
My requirement is to add the value of ${{ steps.getenv.outputs.recenvironments }} to the strategy matrix if it is not null, else nothing to be added.
Below is the GitHub Actions workflow:
  Approvals: 
    name: Approvals
    runs-on:
      group: "ARE-Shared"

    strategy:
      matrix:
        envName: [APP_APPROVAL, DB_APPROVAL,  ${{ steps.getenv.outputs.recenvironments }}]
        #include:
        #   - envName: ${{ steps.getenv.outputs.recenvironments }}
    environment:     ${{ matrix.envName }}

    steps:

      - name: Extract Environment from SERVER_ENVIRONMENT
        id: getenv
        run: |

          #for testing purpose hard-coding the value of variable instead of getting it dynamically. 
          $recenvironments = "Production"
          #$recenvironments = "${{ steps.getsnowdetails.outputs.invhosts_env }}"
          echo "recenvironments=$recenvironments" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"

Unfortunately, I get the following error:
Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/wdadevDBexecutionscripts.yml#L17
error parsing called workflow
".github/workflows/wdadev.yml"
-> "mmctech/DevOps/.github/workflows/newexecutescript.yml@newmmtmp" (source branch with sha:67fb319c3dcd076e9498a84ef1183f04f3cb9ce0)
: You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 154

How can I get the ${{ steps.getsnowdetails.outputs.invhosts_env }} to be part of matrix if it is not null so it populates upon execution?

The output of a step that's part of the job for which you use the matrix can't possibly be part of the matrix itself. The matrix must be known so the jobs can run in the first place. You could use the output of a previous job to build your matrix, though, see docs.

@BenjaminW. i tried using the output of the previous job using envName: [APP_APPROVAL, DB_APPROVAL, ${{ needs.<previousjobname>.outputs.<matrixvariable> }}]
But that still give me syntax error.
I guess i may have to construct the entire matrix variable in the previous job and not be able to substitute a variable in the matrix.

Upon leads from @Benjamin W. I was able to contruct the matrix as below:
  Approvals: 
    name: ${{ matrix.envName }}
    needs: <previousjobname>
    
    runs-on:
      group: "Runner-Shared"

    strategy:
      matrix:
        envName: 
          - APP_APPROVAL
          - DB_APPROVAL
          - "${{ needs.<previousjobname>.outputs.<variable> }}"

    environment:    
      name: ${{ matrix.envName }}

    steps:

      - name: Extract Environment from SERVER_ENVIRONMENT
        id: getenv
        run: |
          Write-Host "Run Success"

